# How do I compare two AssemblyName instances?

Tags: c#, .net

How do I compare two AssemblyName instances to figure out whether they represent the same assembly? The 'Equals' method isn't overriden.

One way I can think of is compare the 'ToString()' results of both the instances but I would prefer an 'Equals' syntax since I need to prepare a list (List) of 'unique' AssemblyName instances and would like to use the 'Contains(AssemblyName item)' method.

Comment: Using an ISet<AssemblyName> implementation, e.g. HashSet<AssemblyName> should yield better performance when dealing with more than very few items. An IEqualityComparer<AssemblyName> implementation will be required then, though. That means, not only Equals, but also GetHashCode will need to be implemented.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/assembly/names "The runtime treats assembly names as case-insensitive when binding to an assembly, but preserves whatever case is used in an assembly name. Several tools in the Windows SDK handle assembly names as case-sensitive. For best results, manage assembly names as though they were case-sensitive." One might want to compare case-insensitively. [StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.stringcomparer.ordinalignorecase) will come in handy, then.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As long as you are using strongly-named assemblies, comparing the output of the [ToString method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.assemblyname.tostring(VS.85).aspx) would be fine, as it outputs the full name of the assembly, [which is supposed to be consistent and seems to be culture-invariant](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.assemblyname(v=VS.85).aspx).

If the assemblies are not strong-named, then one can easily create another assembly with the same name and version number/culture and it would have the same assembly name as yours.

One thing to note though, because the assembly names are the same doesn't mean that the assemblies are the same physical identity; location is *not* part of the assembly name.

Comment: This may not prove adequate if the assemblies are not strong named. I'm pretty sure without strong naming, it's possible to make two assemblies appear to have the same name yet actually be completely different inside.

Comment: @Matt : In my case I can safely assume that I am dealing with strongly named assemblies.

Comment: Strong assembly names are not respected in .NET Core and the modern .NET.

Answer (score 6):

The static method [AssemblyName.ReferenceMatchesDefinition()](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.reflection.assemblyname.referencematchesdefinition) accepts two AssemblyName instances and compares them based on their Name property:

```
using System.Reflection;

var expectedName = new AssemblyName(name);
var actualName = AssemblyName.GetAssemblyName(path);

if (AssemblyName.ReferenceMatchesDefinition(expectedName, actualName))
{
    // The same assemblies
}
```

In some cases, comparing them based on the FullName property might be preferable, though.

Comment: Related Q: [How does AssemblyName.ReferenceMatchesDefinition work?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2494421/2157640)

Answer (score 3):

I would compare the `AssemblyName.FullName` property, as it represents the actual version specific identity of the assembly.

Comment: `AssemblyName.ToString` is overridden to return the same thing as `AssemblyName.FullName`

Comment: @HansOlsson: Comparing the property that contains the actual value you want to compare should still be preferable instead of comparing something that incidentally yields something that happens to work the same right now. `ToString` is generally not intended to return a unique, comparable string representation of an object. You wouldn't compare numbers for equality through `ToString` either, I guess.

Comment: @Joey I don't disagree. I can't say for sure 9 years later, but I'm pretty sure I just meant the comment as a FYI rather than a disagreement with the answer :).

Answer (score 0):

To compare [`AssemblyName`](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.reflection.assemblyname) instances, using [`IEqualityComparer<AssemblyName>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.iequalitycomparer-1) is the way to go. It provides both Equals() and GetHashCode() implementations and it can be used even with standard collections.

For your use case, replacing `List<AssemblyName>` with an [`ISet<AssemblyName>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.iset-1) implementation, e.g. [`HashSet<AssemblyName>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.hashset-1), should yield better performance when dealing with more than very few items. The equality comparer is usually injected into the collection using one of the overloads of its constructor.

But how to get an implementation of the equality comparer? .NET does not provide any standard one with the required semantics, so it is necessary to build a custom one.

First, there are some things to know about the case (in)sensitivity of the assembly names themselves. Microsoft recommends using case-sensitive comparison. For a more nuanced explanation, see a related Q: [Can I rely on specific capitalization of .NET assembly names?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14898042/2157640)

Then, more questions (and design choice points) open up when you dive into the structure of [`AssemblyName`](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.reflection.assemblyname). Is comparing the [fully qualified name](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/standard/assembly/find-fully-qualified-name) (a.k.a. FullName) OK? Are [strong name](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/standard/assembly/strong-named) differences relevant? (Unless in .NET Framework, likely not.) [How does AssemblyName.ReferenceMatchesDefinition work?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2494421/2157640)

Ultimately, it boils down to what you need to achieve. There is no universal solution, which is likely why `AssemblyName` does not have overridden Equals and GetHashCode, why it does not implement `IEquatable<AssemblyName>`, and why there is no standard `IEqualityComparer<AssemblyName>` implementation other than `EqualityComparer<AssemblyName>.Default`, which provides reference equality.