# Can I rely on specific capitalization of .NET assembly names?

Tags: c#, .net, reflection, assemblies

In my code, I want to check if a specific assembly is loaded. I have this code:

```
var assembly = AppDomain.CurrentDomain
    .GetAssemblies()
    .Where(a => a.FullName.StartsWith("Microsoft.WindowsAzure.ServiceRuntime"))
    .SingleOrDefault();
```

Now, this code relies on specific capitalization of the assembly – the comparison is case-sensitive.

Do I need the comparison to be case-insensitive or can I expect the specific capitalization at all times?

Comment: For a Microsoft assembly, yes.

Comment: @Hans Passant: I don't quite get it. Do you mean "shipped by MS"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k8xx4k69.aspx), the runtime treats assembly names as case-insenstive. That is, you won't have two assemblies loaded at the same time with names that *only* differ in their capitalization.

So, if you ONLY want to check for a specific assembly name you should do a case-insensitive comparison using [this overload of StartsWith](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ms131452.aspx) with [StringComparison](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/system.stringcomparison.aspx) `.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase` to avoid the (very rare) case where the capitalization of an assembly name has changed.

```
a.FullName.StartsWith("Microsoft.WindowsAzure.ServiceRuntime",
     StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase)
```

Comment: StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase, or StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase?

Answer (score 0):

The docs acknowledge inconsistencies in the case sensitivity of assembly names and they recommend comparing them case-sensitively:

> The runtime treats assembly names as case-insensitive when binding to an assembly, but preserves whatever case is used in an assembly name. Several tools in the Windows SDK handle assembly names as case-sensitive. For best results, manage assembly names as though they were case-sensitive.
> -- https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/standard/assembly/names

Yet, if you choose to compare the name of the assembly (essentially [`AssemblyName.Name`](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.reflection.assemblyname.name)) case-insensitively, it is not clear whether to compare ordinally or using the invariant culture. I would prefer ordinal comparison in such technical contexts, i.e. [`StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase`](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.stringcomparer.ordinalignorecase) and [`StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase`](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.stringcomparison). As the [best practices for comparing strings](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/standard/base-types/best-practices-strings) advise:

> Use the non-linguistic StringComparison.Ordinal or StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase values instead of string operations based on CultureInfo.InvariantCulture when the comparison is linguistically irrelevant (symbolic, for example).