# How to check assembly exists before calling a class method in C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc

I am working on an application with two supporting DLLs in the Project. `ClassLibrary1.dll` and `ClassLibrary2.dll`. The ClassLibrary2.dll is optional and only used by the `ClassLibrary1.dll`. The application has a feature to import the DLL explicitly. Everything worked fine if I import both DLLs into the application.

The problem arises when I don't import the optional ClassLibrary2.dll.

Here on application start, I am checking whether assembly exists or not:

```
var assemblyName = "ClassLibrary2.dll, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null";
var assemblies = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies();
var assembly = (from a in assemblies
                where a.FullName == assemblyName
                select a).SingleOrDefault();

// this IsClassLibrary2Exists property become true when the DLL exists
if (assembly != null)
{
    Props.IsClassLibrary2Exists = true;          
}
```

Here is How I am calling the ClassLibrary2 method in ClassLibrary1

```
if(Props.IsClassLibrary2Exists){
      ClassLibrary2.SpecialProduct.GetSpecialProduct(Id);
}
```

I am getting an error when the assembly does not exist:

> "System.IO.FileNotFoundException: 'Could not load file or assembly 'ClassLibrary2, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.'"

Comment: It seems you must access the assembly through `assembly` only and not through a `ClassLibrary2` reference.

Comment: `a.FullName == assemblyName` <-- Using a string comparison isn't the best way to do this because it's very brittle. Consider using `ReferenceMatchesDefinition` to compare two `AssemblyName` objects: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3459217/how-do-i-compare-two-assemblyname-instances

Comment: `ClassLibrary2.SpecialProduct.GetSpecialProduct(Id);` <-- This fails because your program has a hardcoded dependency on `ClassLibrary2`: look at your compiled `.exe` in ILSpy and you'll see the entry under "References" - so in your case your `ClassLibrary2` reference isn't really optional at all: the CLR **will always need** `ClassLibrary2` just to JIT your program. If you want an extensibility or "plug-in" feature then you cannot use design-time assembly references to optional assemblies.

Comment: @Dai this is not *exactly* true - the fact that assembly one references assembly two does not necessary mean that JIT will load all references (including the assembly two) as it may never need to JIT methods and types that actually use that assembly two. Granted it is (was?) possible to JIT the whole assembly (like ngen in the past), but for regular execution having a reference to the assembly is not equal to loading that assembly all the time.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov Right, right - I'm making the assumption that the OP's codebase calls `ClassLibrary2.SpecialProduct.GetSpecialProduct(Id)` in a method that will _always_ be JIT'd though (and so will _always fail_) because it's in the same class and method that has the `if(Props.IsClassLibrary2Exists){` check - which means, in this particular case, it's impossible to run the `.exe` _and_ perform the `Props.IsClassLibrary2Exists` check in the same method or type that calls `making the assumption that the OP's codebase calls `ClassLibrary2.SpecialProduct.GetSpecialProduct`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I agree with the comment by Dai that the underlying issue is that `ClassLibrary1` has a hardcoded dependency on `ClassLibrary2` so the matter falls to how this can be decoupled.

One approach that has worked for me is to have an `Interface` class library consisting only of plugin interfaces that the application may attempt to use (but which, at the same time, might not have instances attached). It will be referenced by plugin servers and clients alike.

---

**`Interface` class library**

```
namespace Interface
{
    /// <summary>
    /// To be a plugin for this app requires IPlugin at minimum .
    /// </summary>
    public interface IPlugin { }
    public interface ISpecialProduct : IPlugin
    {
        string GetSpecialProduct(string id);
    }
}
```

---

**ClassLibrary1**

The `SpecialProduct` member is decoupled from `ClassLibrary2` because it's an interface not a class.

```
using Interface; // But 'not' ClassLibrary2
namespace ClassLibrary1
{
    public class Product
    {
        public ISpecialProduct SpecialProduct { get; set; }
    }
}
```

---

**ClassLibrary2**

```
using Interface; // The only dependency
namespace ClassLibrary2
{
    public class SpecialProduct : ISpecialProduct
    {
        public string GetSpecialProduct(string id) => Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
    }
}
```

---

**Test (proof of concept using console app)**

Available plugins are located in the `Plugins` subfolder of the application's run directory. `ClassLibrary2` is *not* initially referenced or loaded.

```
using Interface;
using ClassLibrary1; // But 'not' ClassLibrary2
internal class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.Title = "Test optional lib";
        Assembly assySpecial;
        Product product = new Product(); // In ClassLibrary1

        #region N O T    L O A D E D
        // Try get assy (not strong named or picky about version)
        assySpecial =
            AppDomain
            .CurrentDomain
            .GetAssemblies()
            .FirstOrDefault(_ => _.GetName().Name.Equals("ClassLibrary2"));
        Debug.Assert(assySpecial == null, "Expecting assy not loaded");
        Debug.Assert(product.SpecialProduct == null, "Expecting null SpecialProduct");
        if(product.SpecialProduct == null)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("SpecialProduct is not loaded yet.");
        }
        #endregion N O T    L O A D E D

        #region L O A D
        var pluginPath = Path.Combine(
            AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory,
            "Plugins",
            "ClassLibrary2.dll");
        if(File.Exists(pluginPath)) 
        {
            Assembly.LoadFrom(pluginPath);
        }
        #endregion L O A D

        #region L O A D E D
        assySpecial =
            AppDomain
            .CurrentDomain
            .GetAssemblies()
            .FirstOrDefault(_ => _.GetName().Name.Equals("ClassLibrary2"));

        Debug.Assert(assySpecial != null, "Expecting assy loaded");

        if (assySpecial != null)
        {
            product.SpecialProduct = 
                (ISpecialProduct)
                Activator.CreateInstance(
                    assySpecial
                    .GetTypes()
                    .First(_ => _.Name.Equals("SpecialProduct")));
        }

        Console.WriteLine($"SpecialProduct: {product.SpecialProduct?.GetSpecialProduct("123")}");

        Console.ReadKey();
        #endregion L O A D E D
    }
}
```

[image: console output]

Answer (score -1):

To have any success in preventing one assembly to require the other one you need all access to the "assembly 2" to be done via *methods* that are not executed. Protecting access with `if`  is not enough because whole method need to be JITed first and that requires loading the other assembly.

What *likely* would work:

```
   ... 
   if (Props.IsClassLibrary2Exists)
       DoThingsWithLibrary2();
   ...

   void DoThingsWithLibrary2()
   {
     // access to Library2 feature must be scoped to methods
     // that are not executed
     ClassLibrary2.SpecialProduct.GetSpecialProduct(Id);
   }
```

Note that it is extremely easy to use "the other library" in a way that is hard/impossible to fix at run-time - static properties/constructors can be called at any time and hence referencing anything from the other library there will fail, having fields/properties/method parameters/return to use types from the other library would fail even via reflection... and like many other cases.

If possible prefer to load the assembly dynamically and have it implement shared interfaces so you can limit reflection to instantiation part, but use those classes via strongly typed interfaces.